# Return value of cell if specific cell contains value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Let say my **SHEET1!A1** contains **x** then I want to get the value of **SHEET1!B1**, and my formula for that would be;

```
=IF(SHEET1!A1="x",SHEET1!B1,"")
```

To do that in the entire column I select the entire column and press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

The problem after that

1. The file goes from `28KB` to `40MB` making the document lag and stop working even just when saving. This is because I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to copy down the formula.
2. If **SHEET1!A1** doesn't have **x**, it will return blank or empty cell. What I want is to skip it then fill only the second cell if it does contain **x**.

The expected output would be;
[image: Expected Result]

This is what I have;
[image: Wrong Result]

I'm thinking this is not possible using a formula, maybe a macro would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have office365 you can do this with the "filter" function:

```
  =FILTER(B:B;A:A = "x")
```

Comment: There's a problem with the formula.

Comment: maybe you mean, `=FILTER(B:B,A:A = "x")`. But the result is `#SPILL!`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm on EU Excel which uses semicomma in functions.The "spill" error is because you already have values in the column in which you entered the function, thus obstructing the array to populate.

Comment: What would be the formula if I want to use a different sheet? `=FILTER(SHEET1!B:SHEET1!B;SHEET1!A:SHEET1!A = "x")` doesn't work.

Comment: `=FILTER(SHEET1!B:B,SHEET1!A:A = "x")` this is what I want. Thank you!